# Retain records where two criteria are met, mix of conditional date values and match to a list

Tags: r

I have the below code which creates a data frame:

```
Values_List <- "I611|I613|I614|I639"

df <- 
  read.table(textConnection("ID   Identifier   Date1 Date2
A I611 01/01/2021 03/01/2021
A I611 04/01/2021 08/01/2021
A Z422 09/01/2021 30/01/2021
A I639 08/11/2021 09/11/2021
A B233 10/11/2021 11/11/2021
B Z317 09/01/2021 30/01/2021
B I611 04/02/2021 08/02/2021
C I614 04/02/2021 11/02/2022
D I611 01/01/2022 02/01/2022
D I611 08/01/2022 07/01/2022 
"), header=TRUE)
```

I am looking to filter to keep all rows where value in 'Identifier' is within list 'Values_list' and also, date in 'Date1' of the record immediately below it is within 30 days of 'Date2' in the record. If these criteria are matched, both records are retained. The 'second' record e.g. the one underneath the original record should be retained even if its 'Identifier' value is not within the Values_List, e.g. if 'record A' matches the identifier list and record B has Date1 within 30 days of Date2, that should be retained even if its own 'Identifier' value is not within the Values_List.

The output should therefore look like this:

| ID | Identifier | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | I611 | 01/01/2021 | 03/01/2021 |
| A | I611 | 04/01/2021 | 08/01/2021 |
| A | Z422 | 09/01/2021 | 30/01/2021 |
| D | I611 | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 |
| D | I611 | 08/01/2022 | 30/01/2022 |

The other records are excluded because either the value in 'Identifier' is not within the list or the Date1 value in the record below it within the initial group_by(ID) is not within 30 days of the Date2 value of the record.

Assistance will be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you want `df %>% filter(str_detect(Identifier, Values_List)) %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Date"), dmy)) %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(abs(lead(Date1, default = last(Date1)) - Date2) <= 30) %>%  ungroup`

Comment: Some date values have typo `30701/2022`  is it month/day/year or day/month/year

Comment: Also, `Z422` was not found in your Values_List, so not sure how it is in expected output

Comment: Hi thanks for your input - the row with 'Identifier' value = Z422 should be included because the above row's Identifier is within the Values_List and the Date1 for that row is within 30 days of Date2 in row above it - hope that helps clarify. Any further help would be very much appreciated.